# How do I add a css class to a JQuery Mobile Select Option's text?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

[image: Select with css in text]

I want to add a span to the text of a JQM select so the result looks like the pic below.  I put the code in a html.Raw, but the span tag was removed. The text I tried was :

```
@Html.Raw(Every <span class="subtext">(number...)</span>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try it with some quotes. I'm on my phone and can't test it but probably something like this works:
'Every (number...)'

Note that you can't mix up single and double quotes.

Do you want to add the class to one special element or to all of them?

To all of them would be like this:
$('parentElement li span').addClass ('subtext');